# A python bot issue (I'm a newbie)

Tags: python, bots

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to create a bot for my customers.

The bot should show the USA working visas eligibility by parameters.

The issue is that I've set it to show E-2 visa with 100k+$ available, but seems it doesn't see the condition and shows E-2 available with "no" by 100k$ question.

The same happens with H2-A and H2-B which are set to education == "no", but they show with education =="yes".

Kindly help me to sort it out, thank you.

```
# Visa eligibility checker
print("Welcome to the visa eligibility checker supported by move2usajobs.com job portal.")
# Get country of citizenship
country = input("What is your country of citizenship? ")
treaty_e1_visa_matches = []
treaty_e2_visa_matches = []
treaty_h2_visa_matches = []
non_treaty_visa_matches = []

# Treaty-visa Countries 
if country == "Argentina" or country == "Australia" or country == "Austria" or country == "Belgium" or \
   country == "Bolivia" or country == "Bosnia and Herzegovina" or country == "Brunei" or country == "Canada" or \
   country == "Chile" or country == "China (Taiwan)" or country == "Colombia" or country == "Costa Rica" or \
   country == "Croatia" or country == "Denmark" or country == "Estonia" or country == "Ethiopia" or \
   country == "Finland" or country == "France" or country == "Germany" or country == "Greece" or \
   country == "Honduras" or country == "Iran" or country == "Ireland" or country == "Israel" or \
   country == "Italy" or country == "Japan" or country == "Jordan" or country == "Kazakhstan" or \
   country == "Korea (South)" or country == "Kosovo" or country == "Kyrgyzstan" or country == "Latvia" or \
   country == "Liberia" or country == "Lithuania" or country == "Luxembourg" or country == "Macedonia" or \
   country == "Mexico" or country == "Moldova" or country == "Mongolia" or country == "Montenegro" or \
   country == "Morocco" or country == "Netherlands" or country == "New Zealand" or country == "Norway" or \
   country == "Oman" or country == "Pakistan" or country == "Panama" or country == "Paraguay" or \
   country == "Philippines" or country == "Poland" or country == "Serbia" or country == "Singapore" or \
   country == "Slovak Republic" or country == "Slovenia" or country == "Spain" or country == "Sri Lanka" or \
   country == "Suriname" or country == "Sweden" or country == "Switzerland" or country == "Thailand" or \
   country == "Togo" or country == "Trinidad and Tobago" or country == "Tunisia" or country == "Turkey" or \
   country == "Ukraine" or country == "United Kingdom" or country == "Yugoslavia":
    treaty_e1_visa_matches.append("E-1")


# Get education level
    education = input("Do you have a bachelor's degree? (yes/no) ")
# Get information to determine possible visa matches countries
    need_training_not_available_in_country = input("Do you need to get a training that is not available in your country? (yes/no) ")
    company_in_usa = input("Does the company you work for have an office in the USA? (yes/no) ")
    recognized_extraordinary_ability = input("Do you have recognized extraordinary abilities? (yes/no) ")
    athlete_or_entertainer_or_artist = input("Are you an athlete, entertainer, or artist? (yes/no) ")
    cultural_worker = input("Are you a cultural worker? (yes/no) ")
    age_under_35 = input("Is your age less than 35? (yes/no) ")
    journalist_or_media_worker = input("Are you a journalist or a media worker? (yes/no) ")
    executive_or_top_manager = input("Are you an executive or a top manager in your company? (yes/no) ")
    have_100k_dollars = input("Do you have $100,000 or more? (yes/no) ")
    exceptional_ability = input("Do you have exceptional ability in arts, science, or business? (yes/no) ")
# Determine possible visa matches for treaty countries
    if age_under_35 == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("J-1")
    if recognized_extraordinary_ability == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("O-1")
    if country == "Canada" or country == "Mexico" and education == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("TN")
    if country == "Chile" or country == "Singapore" and education =="yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("H1-B1")
    if athlete_or_entertainer_or_artist == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("P-1")
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("P-3")
    if cultural_worker == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("Q-1")
    if education == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("H1-B")
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("EB-2")
        if company_in_usa == "yes":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("L-1")
        if journalist_or_media_worker == "yes":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("I")
        if executive_or_top_manager == "yes":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("L-1")
        if recognized_extraordinary_ability == "yes":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("EB-1")
        if education == "yes" and country == "Australia":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("E-3")

    if country == "Albania" or country == "Argentina" or country == "Armenia" or country == "Australia" or \
   country == "Austria" or country == "Azerbaijan" or country == "Bahrain" or country == "Bangladesh" or \
   country == "Belgium" or country == "Bosnia and Herzegovina" or country == "Bulgaria" or country == "Cameroon" or \
   country == "Canada" or country == "Chile" or country == "China (Taiwan)" or country == "Colombia" or \
   country == "Congo (Brazzaville)" or country == "Congo (Kinshasa)" or country == "Costa Rica" or country == "Croatia" or \
   country == "Czech Republic" or country == "Denmark" or country == "Ecuador" or country == "Egypt" or \
   country == "Estonia" or country == "Ethiopia" or country == "Finland" or country == "France" or \
   country == "Georgia" or country == "Germany" or country == "Greece" or country == "Grenada" or \
   country == "Honduras" or country == "Iran" or country == "Ireland" or country == "Israel" or \
   country == "Italy" or country == "Jamaica" or country == "Japan" or country == "Jordan" or \
   country == "Kazakhstan" or country == "South Korea" or country == "Kosovo" or country == "Kyrgyzstan" or \
   country == "Latvia" or country == "Liberia" or country == "Lithuania" or country == "Luxembourg" or \
   country == "Macedonia" or country == "Mexico" or country == "Moldova" or country == "Mongolia" or \
   country == "Montenegro" or country == "Morocco" or country == "Nepal" or country == "Netherlands" or \
   country == "New Zealand" or country == "Nicaragua" or country == "Nigeria" or country == "Norway" or \
   country == "Oman" or country == "Pakistan" or country == "Panama" or country == "Paraguay" or \
   country == "Philippines" or country == "Poland" or country == "Romania" or country == "Serbia" or \
   country == "Senegal" or country == "Singapore" or country == "Slovak Republic" or country == "Slovenia" or \
   country == "Spain" or country == "Sri Lanka" or country == "Suriname" or country == "Sweden" or \
   country == "Switzerland" or country == "Thailand" or country == "Togo" or country == "Trinidad and Tobago" or \
   country == "Tunisia" or country == "Turkey" or country == "Ukraine" or country == "United Kingdom" or \
   country == "Yugoslavia" and have_100k_dollars == "yes":
        treaty_e2_visa_matches.append("E-2")

if country == "Andorra" or country == "Argentina" or country == "Australia" or country == "Austria" or \
   country == "Barbados" or country == "Belgium" or country == "Brazil" or country == "Brunei" or \
   country == "Bulgaria" or country == "Canada" or country == "Chile" or country == "Colombia" or \
   country == "Costa Rica" or country == "Croatia" or country == "Czech Republic" or country == "Denmark" or \
   country == "Dominican Republic" or country == "Ecuador" or country == "El Salvador" or country == "Estonia" or \
   country == "Fiji" or country == "Finland" or country == "France" or country == "Germany" or \
   country == "Greece" or country == "Grenada" or country == "Guatemala" or country == "Haiti" or \
   country == "Honduras" or country == "Hungary" or country == "Iceland" or country == "Ireland" or \
   country == "Israel" or country == "Italy" or country == "Jamaica" or country == "Japan" or \
   country == "Kiribati" or country == "Latvia" or country == "Liechtenstein" or country == "Lithuania" or \
   country == "Luxembourg" or country == "Macedonia" or country == "Madagascar" or country == "Malawi" or \
   country == "Malaysia" or country == "Maldives" or country == "Malta" or country == "Marshall Islands" or \
   country == "Mauritius" or country == "Mexico" or country == "Micronesia" or country == "Moldova" or \
   country == "Monaco" or country == "Mongolia" or country == "Montenegro" or country == "Morocco" or \
   country == "Mozambique" or country == "Nauru" or country == "Nepal" or country == "Netherlands" or \
   country == "New Zealand" or country == "Nicaragua" or country == "Norway" or country == "Panama" or \
   country == "Papua New Guinea" or country == "Paraguay" or country == "Peru" or country == "Philippines" or \
   country == "Poland" or country == "Portugal" or country == "Romania" or country == "Saint Kitts and Nevis" or \
   country == "Saint Lucia" or country == "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" or country == "Samoa" or \
   country == "San Marino" or country == "Serbia" or country == "Seychelles" or country == "Singapore" or \
   country == "Slovakia" or country == "Slovenia" or country == "Solomon Islands" or country == "South Africa" or \
   country == "South Korea" and education == "no":
    treaty_h2_visa_matches.append("H-2A")
    treaty_h2_visa_matches.append("H-2B")

# Combine treaty and non-treaty visa matches
all_visa_matches = treaty_e1_visa_matches + treaty_e2_visa_matches + treaty_h2_visa_matches + non_treaty_visa_matches

if len(all_visa_matches) > 0:
    print("You may be eligible for the following visa types:")
    for visa_type in all_visa_matches:
        print("-", visa_type)
else:
    print("Unfortunately, there are no visa types you are eligible for at this time.")

print("Thank you for using the visa eligibility checker.")
```

I've tried to ask chatGPT but it doesn't help.

Comment: By the way `country == "A" or country == "B" or country == "C"` can be expressed shorter as `country in ["A", "B", "C"]`

Comment: `condition1 or condition 2 and condition 3` is true if `condition1` is true or if `condition2 and condition3` is true. So your "have_100k_dollars" requirement only applies to "Yugoslavia". In any case, it's better to remove all those 'or's as stated in @AlexeyLarionov's comment.

Comment: You probably want to use sets rather than lists. Like: `treaty_visa_countries` = set(["Argentina", "Australia",....])` Then `if country in treaty_visa_contries"`. Also should probably use sets for your matches variables as you can do set operations which seem to match the kind of logic you want.

Comment: Don't ask ChatGPT, CoPilot or any other machine when you want to learn something.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire You can use a set literal instead of calling the constructor on a list: `country in {"Argentina", "Australia", ...}`

Comment: Yeah I know, but for a noob I thought it better to make it explicit so they don't confuse it with dict syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have had an indentation error in there. I've adapted your code a little like below. I tested it with the 100k example and the education, and I think it works for those now.

As the comments on your question said, better to work with lists for the country names. You might want to use case-insensitive matching in case people type the countries in all lower case. Let me know if it works

```
# Visa eligibility checker
print("Welcome to the visa eligibility checker supported by move2usajobs.com job portal.\n\n")

# different visa conditions
treaty_e1_visa_matches = []
treaty_e2_visa_matches = []
treaty_h2_visa_matches = []
non_treaty_visa_matches = []

# Treaty-visa Countries 
E1_countries = ["Argentina","Australia","Austria"]
E2_countries = ["Albania","Argentina","Yugoslavia"]
H2_countries = ["Andorra","Argentina","South Korea"]

# Get country of citizenship
country = input("What is your country of citizenship? ")

# Get education level
education = input("Do you have a bachelor's degree? (yes/no) ")

# Get information to determine possible visa matches countries
need_training_not_available_in_country = input("Do you need to get a training that is not available in your country? (yes/no) ")
company_in_usa = input("Does the company you work for have an office in the USA? (yes/no) ")
recognized_extraordinary_ability = input("Do you have recognized extraordinary abilities? (yes/no) ")
athlete_or_entertainer_or_artist = input("Are you an athlete, entertainer, or artist? (yes/no) ")
cultural_worker = input("Are you a cultural worker? (yes/no) ")
age_under_35 = input("Is your age less than 35? (yes/no) ")
journalist_or_media_worker = input("Are you a journalist or a media worker? (yes/no) ")
executive_or_top_manager = input("Are you an executive or a top manager in your company? (yes/no) ")
have_100k_dollars = input("Do you have $100,000 or more? (yes/no) ")
exceptional_ability = input("Do you have exceptional ability in arts, science, or business? (yes/no) ")

# Determine possible visa matches for treaty countries
if age_under_35 == "yes":
    non_treaty_visa_matches.append("J-1")
    if recognized_extraordinary_ability == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("O-1")
    if country == "Canada" or country == "Mexico" and education == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("TN")
    if country == "Chile" or country == "Singapore" and education =="yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("H1-B1")
    if athlete_or_entertainer_or_artist == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("P-1")
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("P-3")
    if cultural_worker == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("Q-1")
    if education == "yes":
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("H1-B")
        non_treaty_visa_matches.append("EB-2")
        if company_in_usa == "yes":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("L-1")
        if journalist_or_media_worker == "yes":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("I")
        if executive_or_top_manager == "yes":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("L-1")
        if recognized_extraordinary_ability == "yes":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("EB-1")
        if education == "yes" and country == "Australia":
            non_treaty_visa_matches.append("E-3")

  
# country check
if country in E1_countries:
    treaty_e1_visa_matches.append("E-1")
elif country in E2_countries:
    if country != "Yugoslavia":
        treaty_e2_visa_matches.append("E-2")
    elif country == "Yugoslavia" and have_100k_dollars == "yes":
        treaty_e2_visa_matches.append("E-2")
elif country in H2_countries:
    if country != "South Korea":
        treaty_h2_visa_matches.append("H-2A")
        treaty_h2_visa_matches.append("H-2B")
    elif country =="South Korea" and education == "no":
        treaty_h2_visa_matches.append("H-2A")
        treaty_h2_visa_matches.append("H-2B")
    
# Combine treaty and non-treaty visa matches
all_visa_matches = treaty_e1_visa_matches + treaty_e2_visa_matches + treaty_h2_visa_matches + non_treaty_visa_matches

if len(all_visa_matches) > 0:
    print("\n\nYou may be eligible for the following visa types:")
    for visa_type in all_visa_matches:
        print("-", visa_type)
else:
    print("\n\nUnfortunately, there are no visa types you are eligible for at this time.")

print("\n\nThank you for using the visa eligibility checker.")
```